# HTC Explorer wallpaper display problem

Tags: wallpaper

I have HTC Explorer, when I download a wallpaper from net and try to set it as wallpaper, the phone first asks me to crop it, so I crop it, but some portion from all the four sides of the cropped image is not displayed.

And now the main problem, the phone has 320x480 screen resolution, I have a wallpaper from net with the same resolution, but the phone still asks me to crop it, while cropping most of the times I have to let go the image from top and bottom, the horizontal part of the image is available but vertical part needs to be cropped.

More interestingly, I created a jpg file on ms paint on computer with 320x480 pix and transferred it to the phone, even then it asked me to crop it and after cropping when I saw the wallpaper to my surprise it was not what or how the original image was cropped.

can you guys help me, thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> some portion from all the four sides of the cropped image is not displayed.

At least it seems so -- but that's perfectly normal ("works as designed"). Android does not think of it as a background image solely for the "recent homescreen", but rather for your "collection of homescreen pages". If you swipe through your homescreens left-to-right (or in the opposite direction), and watch the background image while doing so, you will notice it slightly sliding along. So the "left side" of your background image aligns with the left-most "page", while the "right side" does the same with the right-most page.

> the phone has 320x480 screen resolution, I have a wallpaper from net with the same resolution, but the phone still asks me to crop it

The reason for this hopefully became clear with above explanation. So generally spoken, you will need a picture with the actual *height* of your screen, but being *wider* than the actual screen width.